# How to copy and paste as values Google Apps Script/Sheets from one spreadsheet to another?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

So I have a huge spreadsheet with 9k rows and more than 30 columns. I want to copy this spreadsheet to another spreadsheet (Values only).

Previously I was using this code successfully, but due to the increase in data, the script now times out (1800s +). Is there a way to optimize this script or maybe an alternative option altogether?

```
function temp() {

  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XYZ'); // sss = source spreadsheet
  //var ss = sss.getSheets()[4]; // ss = source sheet

  var ss = sss.getSheets(); // ss = source sheet
  var id=4; //default number

  for(var i in ss)
  {
    var sheet = ss[i];
    if(sheet.getName()== "ABC")
    {  id=i;
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log(id);
  
  ss=sss.getSheets()[id];

  //Get full range of data
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();
  //get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();
  //get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // tss = target spreadsheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('ABC'); // ts = target sheet
  //set the target range to the values of the source data
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);


}
```

Comment: Probably it will work faster via Sheet API. But it's a tricky beast: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts

Comment: Specifically: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.sheets/copyTo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of the script.

In this case, I would like to propose to use Sheets API. This has already been mentioned in [the Yuri Khristich's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71165529/how-to-copy-and-paste-as-values-google-apps-script-sheets-from-one-spreadsheet-t#comment125797432_71165529). Also, when the benchmark is measured between Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp) and Sheets API, when Sheets API is used for reading and writing the values for Spreadsheet, it was confirmed that the process cost could be reduced. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)

When Sheets API is used for your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And please set the source Spreadsheet ID and the sheet names.

```js
function temp() {
  var sourceSpreadsheetId = "XYZ"; // Please set the source Spreadsheet ID.
  var destinationSpreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var sourceValues = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(sourceSpreadsheetId, "ABC").values;
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({values: sourceValues}, destinationSpreadsheetId, "ABC", {valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"});
}
```

#### References:

- [Benchmark: Reading and Writing Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

Comment: Thanks a ton, worked like a charm. Reduced my cost process by more than 90%!

Comment: @VivekGupta, that's a lot of improvement!!

Comment: @Tanaike, so the script was running perfectly, but now I see that my sheet is not getting updated past the 8798 row. (Total rows 8956).

Comment: @Vivek Gupta Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor skill. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation of `so the script was running perfectly, but now I see that my sheet is not getting updated past the 8798 row. (Total rows 8956).`. But I would like to support you. So can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including your current script for correctly replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Copy from one spreadsheet to another

```
function copyfromonetoanother() {
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("dssid");
  const ssh = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const vs = ssh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const dsh = dss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

If you wish to select the source range:

```
function copyfromonetoanother() {
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("dssid");
  const ssh = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const vs = ssh.activeRange().getValues();
  const dsh = dss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

This function appends to the bottom of the destination sheet

```
function appenddatatobottomofdestination() {
  const sssId = "source spreadsheet id"; 
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sssId);
  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dssId = dss.getId();
  const ssh = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');//Source sheet
  const srg = ssh.getRange(1,1,ssh.getLastRow(),ssh.getLastColumn());
  const dsh = dss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");//Destination sheet
  var vs = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(sssId, `${ssh.getName()}!${srg.getA1Notation()}`).values;
  const drg = dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, vs.length,vs[0].length);//appends to bottom of spreadsheet
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({values: vs}, dssId, `${dsh.getName()}!${drg.getA1Notation()}`, {valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"});
}
```

Comment: The code runs well but Tanaike's solution reduced the time by quite a huge margin. I have saved both the codes just in case. Thanks!

Comment: The first version is quite slow the second version is much faster.  The third version is similar to Tanaikes although it appends additional data to the bottom of the destination sheet.